# How many ternary strings of length 4 have exactly one 1?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Answer: Ternary strings have symbols 0, 1, and 2. If there is exactly one 1, then there are 3 positions the one can be in and 2*2*2 ways to fill the other 3 blanks with a 0 or a 2. So the answer is 3*2*2*2 = 24.

I don't understand why there can only be 3 positions the one can be in?

Comment: The answer is wrong. The 1 can be in four positions.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that it's restricting leading zero?

Comment: generally, "strings" do not have the leading zero restriction as they use the same definition as in computer science: a sequence of alphanumeric characters.  Had the question asked "4 digit ternary numbers" then yes, leading zero restricted.

Comment: Came across the same problem with the same solution and was glad Google could assure my I wasn't crazy for thinking it was 32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that there are four places to put the $1$, even if leading zeros are prohibited.  Usually with strings leading zeros are allowed, so your implied answer of $4 \cdot 2^3=32$ is a good one.